# Array of Sockets Java

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I'm creating server and client java applications. I would like to create an array to store my sockets in. I'm using eclipse, and when I type in this line:

```
Socket[] sockets = new Socket[3];
```

Eclipse gives me an error saying "The resource type Socket[] does not implement java.lang.AutoCloseable".

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Try/Catch Statement:

```
try (
                Socket[] sockets = new Socket[3]; //Line giving me error
                ServerSocket serverSocket =
                    new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(ip));
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();     
                ServerClient client = new ServerClient(clientSocket);

                PrintWriter out =
                    new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);                   
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                //User input
                BufferedReader stdIn =
                    new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(System.in))
            ) {
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    out.println(inputLine);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
                    + port + " or listening for a connection");
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                continue;
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: did you use try catch block with resources?

Comment: I'm new to java, so I'm not quite sure what that means. I edited the post to show the try/catch statement it's in.

Comment: socket api are close-able as I have found right now, just can you take out what you have in parentheses in try  and put them after { this to see what happens?

Comment: I do not see you using this array at all.

Comment: @PM77-1 The error isn't about Socket, it is about Socket[].

Comment: @EJP - You're absolutely right.  I spelled it out in my answer.

Comment: @PM 77 This isn't the finished program. I'll write the code that uses the array later.

Answer (score 2):

While [`Socket`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b129/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) class itself implements [`AutoCloseable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface, **array** of Sockets - **does not**.

To put it in simple terms: you cannot open or close an array.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code I recevie this error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: try-with-resources not applicable to variable type
    (java.net.Socket[] cannot be converted to java.lang.AutoCloseable)
```

I advice you not to use try catch block with resources when you want to define your socket array.

```
       try (
            your rest of code
        ) { 
    define your array here --->  Socket[] sockets = new Socket[3];
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                out.println(inputLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
           your rest of code
```

Note: Socket class implements Closeable and AutoCloseable , yet array cannot be defined in try block like you tried to do

Comment: Could you tell me what try with resources is? I honestly don't get it. I think if I understood what it was, it would be easier for me to fix it.

Comment: it is new way of try catch block since java 7. if you have something closable you can put them between () and it will be closed automatically. like scanner , resutlset , so do not need to close them manually. check this out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: @user2621270 See [The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Answer (score 0):

The resources defined in a try-with-resources block must all be auto-closeable. That's what it's for. Socket[] is not AutoCloseable, so it cannot be defined there. Move the declaration before the try. Ditto for any other resources you get the error on. Don't treat it as a general declaration block. It isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can outsmart this problem easily, just create a class containing a socket connection, then build an array of this class object.

Build the class:

`Class example
{
Socket con;`

The constructor and extra code here
...

}

Then just build the array:

example[] arr=new example[3];